# Is the divergence of the curl of a $2D$ vector field also supposed to be zero?

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields, divergence-operator, curl

In three dimensions, it seems pretty straightforward to prove the identity that for any vector field $\mathbf{A}$,

$$\nabla \cdot (\nabla \times \mathbf{A}) = 0$$

Does this identity still hold true when $\mathbf{A}$ is a 2-dimensional vector field?  For instance, if

$$\mathbf{A} = \langle xy^2, xy^2 \rangle$$

Then the curl of that field would end up being a scalar field defined by

$$y^2 - x2y$$

Which, if reinterpreted as a vector field $\langle y^2-x2y, y^2-x2y \rangle$, does not have zero-divergence.

Does this interpretation make sense, and therefore the original identity doesn't hold in $2$-dimensions, or is taking the divergence of the curl of a vector field simply not applicable in two dimensions?

Comment: Don't forget the $\hat{k}$ when you take curl of A. Then when you take divergence it is zero!

Comment: It makes sense if you turn the 2D vector field into a 3D one by adding a constant $z$-component; then the curl points in the $z$-direction (in your example, it's $\langle 0, 0, y^2 - 2xy\rangle$) and the divergence is clearly zero.

Comment: @ConnorHarris Yes, I am aware that the scalar field could be interpreted as the z-component, making the identity true, but that's why I was wondering if the identity only works in three dimensions... re-interpreting the scalar-field as another 2D vector field doesn't seem to always produce zero-divergence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't make sense, it is fundamental that it is in three dimensions, normally you would write:

$$\mathbf{A}=(0,0,f(x,y))$$

Then the identity holds true, for your $\mathbf{A}$, you have:

$$\mathbf{A}=(f(a,y),g(x,y),0)$$ and then your curl will have components in the $z$ direction which you need to take into account.

Comment: So there isn't a two dimensional definition for curl, it is always in 3-dimensions?

Comment: Yes. You need three dimensions.

Comment: @Jason: the reasons have to do with the fact that cross products don't exist except in three and (sort of) seven dimensions, and ultimately with Hurwitz's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(composition_algebras)